# Can't remove index.php without 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and Apache and I have followed this steps:

1- mod_rewrite module is eneabled? YES

2- htaccess.txt renamed to .htaccess

3- set "Use URL Rewriting" to YES.

And this is what I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server.

The web is located in /var/www/
The .htaccess is located in /var/www/

And this is my .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/dq1TYs1t

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does the logs show. And is allowoverride enabled for that directory ?

Comment: How can I see the logs? thanks dude

Comment: allowoverride was "none"

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `allowoverride` was set to `none`, your .htaccess file will be ignored.  You need to set `allowoverride` to `all`   the other option is leave `allowoverride` at `none`, and take the contents of the .htaccess file and incorporate it into your apache configuration file. This has the benefit of being slightly faster as apache doesn't need to look in directory tree for .htaccess files (they are really good to allow users that don't have access to the configs the ability to override the base settings,  but if you have access to /var/www you should also have access to make changes to the config files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to enable any mod_rewrite module.

Need to enable URL rewriting option in global configuration. Also need to rename htaccess.txt file to .htaccess.

please check there is no any third party component of security like admin tools are enable or installed which is blocking this mod rewrite option.